# yet another server low drive space script. Not interested in output to html or changing output format

Tags: powershell

All, I would like to know what is wrong with the following. 
I am not interested in output to html or changing output format

```
$servers = Get-Content "c:\x\servers.txt";
$File = "C:\x\serverslowdrivespace.txt"
$datetime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_HH:mm";
Write-Host $datetime
$datetime | Out-File $File
"`n" | Out-File $File -Append
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
#Write-Host $server
$server | Out-File $File -Append
Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT * from Win32_logicaldisk WHERE DriveType ='3'
-AND (($_.freespace/$_.Size)*100) -le 10)" | Format-Table DeviceID, @{ Name 
= "Size(GB)" ; Expression = { [decimal] ( "{0:N0}" -f ($_.size / 
1gb) ) } }, @{ Name = "Free Space(GB)" ; Expression = { [decimal] 
( "{0:N0}" -f ($_.freespace / 1gb) ) } }, @{ Name = "Free (%)" ; Expression 
= { "{0,6:P0}" -f (($_.freespace / 1gb) / ( $_.size / 1gb )) } } -AutoSize 
| Out-File $File -Append
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with it? Does it not work?

Comment: Powershell v 2.0  .  It says its an invalid query

Comment: What does? `Get-WmiObject`? Can you run that query manually? Also I don't see where you are running a query against the remote server in there. Did I miss it?

Comment: You've mixed standard WML and powershell syntax in your query. The logical AND is just `AND` not `-AND`. Less than is `<` not `-le`. You can't use `$_` in there. There are mismatched parentheses. Perhaps you are missing some text because you aren't even hitting a remote server when you run this.

Comment: Thank you mike z.  That helped.  I made the following corrections   Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server -query "SELECT * from Win32_logicaldisk WHERE DriveType ='3' AND (($drive.freespace/$drive.Size)*100) < 10)" | Format-Table DeviceID, @{ Name = "Size(GB)" ; Expression = { [decimal] ( "{0:N0}" -f ($_.size / 1gb) ) } }, @{ Name = "Free Space(GB)" ; Expression = { [decimal] ( "{0:N0}" -f ($_.freespace / 1gb) ) } }, @{ Name = "Free (%)" ; Expression = { "{0,6:P0}" -f (($_.freespace / 1gb) / ( $_.size / 1gb )) } } -AutoSize | Out-File $File -Append

Comment: Is there any way someone can be as kind as mike z and suggest other errors in coding?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are having at this point is that you are using $drive, but $drive is never defined, because it just doesn't work that way. I don't know of a way to make a WMI query include a calculated result as a part of it's WHERE clause. Instead what I would suggest you do is pipe all of your drivetype='3' drives to a Where clause in PowerShell. That way you can filter it down to just the drives with low free space. In the following suggestion I create custom objects with the calculated properties that you created in your Format-Table selections, just to try and keep things clean. If you have issues try removing the line breaks after the pipes, I don't know if that's PSv2 friendly.

```
$servers = Get-Content "c:\x\servers.txt"
$File = "C:\x\serverslowdrivespace.txt"
$datetime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_HH:mm"
Write-Host $datetime
$datetime | Out-File $File
"`n" | Out-File $File -Append
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    $server | Out-File $File -Append

    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server -query "SELECT * from Win32_logicaldisk WHERE DriveType ='3'" | #Query server for hard drives
        Where{(($_.freespace/$_.Size)*100) -lt 10} | #Filter for drives with less than 10% free space
        ForEach{New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            "DeviceID" = $_.DeviceID
            "Size(GB)" = [decimal] ( "{0:N0}" -f ($_.size / 1gb) )
            "Free Space(GB)" = [decimal] ( "{0:N0}" -f ($_.freespace / 1gb) )
            "Free (%)" = "{0,6:P0}" -f (($_.freespace / 1gb) / ( $_.size / 1gb ))
            }
        } |
        Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File $File -Append
}
```